# How to setStyleSheet for QLabel in a specific class in Qt

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qlabel

I have a testing sample like this:
In `class B`, which only has a `QVector` to store some `QLabel` like this:

```
class B : public QWidget
{
public:
    B(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QVector<QLabel*> mLbls;
};
```

And in `class A`, I have the following code:

```
A::A(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    QWidget *mWidget = new QWidget(this);
    QHBoxLayout *hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(mWidget);

    B testingB;
    testingB.mLbls.resize(5);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        testingB.mLbls[i] = new QLabel(mWidget);
        testingB.mLbls[i]->setText(QString::number(i));
        hLayout->addWidget(testingB.mLbls[i]);
    }
    setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: red;}"); //I want to set the QLabel bg color to red

    mWidget->setLayout(hLayout);
    setCentralWidget(mWidget);
}
```

So what I am trying to do is set all `QLabel` that ONLY in `Class B` to red color. But the problem is, if I use `setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: red;}");`, all the `QLabel`(even the `QLabel` in `Class A`) will be set to red background color. 
I do not know how to set all the stylesheet only for `CLass B` object. And I know I could use this way to implement what I am trying to do:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    testingB.mLbls[i] = new QLabel(mWidget);
    testingB.mLbls[i]->setText(QString::number(i));
    testingB.mLbls[i]->setStyleSheet("QLabel {background-color: red;}"); //new added
    hLayout->addWidget(testingB.mLbls[i]);
}
```

By using that way, I think that so troublesome to set stylesheet for them one by one individually, besides sometimes I may need to set some `QLabel` stylesheet differently and the rest of them just have the same stylesheet. If I have more objects and set each of them one by one, that may cost a lot of time.
So I assume there is a way to set stylesheet for some objects in a `class` once for all. Hope that I explain my question clearly. To solve that problem, what can I do?
 Thanks.

Comment: Why do you declare B as a widget, I think it's a container and not a widget since you never add it to the window?

Comment: @eyllanesc oh, maybe I made a mistake there, because I thought that should be a widget, I am just kind of confused about these concepts. But a container or a widget maybe don't really matter, I just want to learn how to set style sheet for all the 'QLabel' only in 'Class B'. So is there a way that you can show me how?

Answer (score 1):

Qt CSS syntax allows you to select children for the CSS rules ([Qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types)), but it is based on the parentship of QObjects not in which class contains pointers to the QLabel.

This CSS will only apply to `QLabel` objects which are children or grand children of a `YourContainerClassWidget` object.

```
// C++
auto container = new YourContainerClassWidget;
auto label = QLabel(container); // The label is now a child of container

// CSS
YourContainerClassWidget QLabel { // Descendant selector
    background-color: red;
}

// You can also apply only to direct children with this syntax
YourContainerClassWidget > QLabel { // Child selector
    background-color: red;
}
```